# error:expected expression else in C

Tags: c

when i want to use else into while, i have an error.

```
ft_putnbr.c:27:2: error: expected expression
        else
        ^
1 error generated.
```

My code is:

```
void    ft_putnbr(int nb)    //reprogram the function putnbr
{
        while(nb >= 10)
        {
            ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
            ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            ft_putchar('0' + nb);
        }
}
```

I don't know why there is this problem.. 
Can you help me?

Comment: while+else is not correct C. Learn to write C.

Answer (score 3):

`while..else` is not a valid C construct.

Did you perhaps mean `if..else`?

Comment: Thank you, i've found the problem now :)

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no `while - else` clause. In language like python, there is a `for-else` clause but still there is no `while-else`. You need to change `while` to `if` or remove `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while` with `if`. If I am not wrong you are trying to break number into digits here?